# Examples of vector subspaces of the real line?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm a beginner of the vector subspace notion. I'm trying to think about a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ which is not $0$ or $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Every vector space over a field has a unique (up to isomorphism) non-negative integer dimension. $\{0\}$ has dimension 0 and $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension 1. What would the dimension of a subspace be?

Comment: If you'd be willing to change "over the field $\mathbb R$" to "over the field $\mathbb Q$, then you can get a HUGE NUMBER (uncountably many, in fact) of vector subspaces of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to think about something that doesn't exist!

Indeed, if $V ≠ \{0\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$, let $a≠0$ in $V$. Then, $x = x/a \cdot a \in V$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, so that $V = \Bbb R$.

(This is not only true for $\Bbb R$: you can generalize this to every field $K$. For instance if $V \subset K$ is a subspace, then $\dim_K(V) ≤ \dim_K(K)$ so that $V$ has dimension $0$ or $1$, and then $V = \{0\}$ or $V=K$).